# How to use sed to replace partial of a find

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, grep

some of the lines in a file look like this:

```
 LOB ("VALUE") STORE AS SECUREFILE "L_MS_WRKNPY_VALUE_0000000011"(
 LOB ("INDEX_XML") STORE AS SECUREFILE "L_HRRPTRY_INDX_L_0000000011"(
```

What I can assume is that in the `"*"` the string starts with an `L_` and ends in 10 chars number.

I want for each line that:

1. start with `LOB` (white-space before the `LOB`)
2. inside `""` the first two letters are `L_`
3. line always ends with `"(`

replace the last 10 chars in the `""` with variable.

all I manage to do is:
`cat /tmp/out.log | sed 's/_[0-9_]*/$NUM/g' > /tmp/newout.log`

to find the required rows I run:
`grep "^ LOB" create_tables_clean.sql | grep "\"L_"`

However I dont know how to combine the two and get what I wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/(\sLOB.*"L_.+_)([0-9]{10})("\()/\1'$myVar'\3/'
```

Replace `$myVar` with your variable, obviously.

[image]

I made three capturing groups:

```
(\sLOB.*"L_.+_)  #catches everything until the 10 numbers
([0-9]{10})      #catches the 10 numbers
("\()            #catches the last "(
```

The first capturing group matches only if your line starts with `LOB` (with a preceeding whitespace) and contains `"L_`.
Then you simply substitute the second capturing group (containing only the 10 numbers) with your variable while keeping the first and third capturing group (`\1'$myVar'\3`).

Your whole call would look like

```
cat /tmp/out.log | sed -r 's/(\sLOB.*"L_.+_)([0-9]{10})("\()/\1'$NUM'\3/g' > /tmp/newout.log
```

(notice I added the `g`-modifier to the regex, so it will match every occurence)

Comment: BTW you are missing `^` before `(\sLOB.*"L_.+_)`

Comment: @nir I ommitted `^` because it looks like each `LOB ...` has its own line. Of course, if you have nested ones on a single line, then you need to add a `^`.

Answer (score 0):

several useless characters are in accepted sed command, here is shorter one.

```
sed -r 's/(LOB.*"L_.*)([0-9]{10})("\()/\1'$myVar'\3/' file
```

Second, @Basti M, when you need echo with double quotes in string, use singe quotes, then you needn't escape the double quotes.

```
echo 'LOB ("VALUE") STORE AS SECUREFILE "L_MS_WRKNPY_VALUE_0000000011"('
```